# How to compare encrypted private keys?

Tags: encryption, openssl, key-generation

Is it possible to compare encrypted private keys if you do not have the passphrase?
E.g.:
`openssl genrsa -out unencryptedprivkey.pem 2048`
`openssl rsa -in unencryptedprivkey.pem -aes128 -out aes128encprivkey.pem`
`openssl rsa -in unencryptedprivkey.pem -aes128 -out aes128encprivkey2.pem`

`cat aes128encprivkey2.pem`

> !-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
>   Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
>   DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,0468AF97F2CA19C8C5860D1BA506B341
>   MwYCfvtLgYzjCnJNe0MNUKnkjnkzTRG6nQX1BbE9AQEdfEQO1FOJI7qjFNVihITB
>   En0i2lcS7dZ7hswqHt0cPUzKU5tEyMfbDNeCl6mg9QlFeobWFczqAf3Ifq1vKwWr
>   S4src/8POhJsvbK10bqHmlbaBK7wPcKSBvEGP8vt8FtqyE40q1uu9cxAcG4LkpF5
>   JZHy9svhQoPuz1bqPSTbUaLMxm2YEmdzuDyrC3IyN6dmEYzav93f07JvD7aSYgjV
>   MJuBcVKMt8HbgAKlq9jgB2Ubwsi9RtWTd/e5SRw0x7C1ImdlXwubv724N9NBRV67
>   4iHgIdpDBit3+5wD400CNOBr4AItts4wpC6ydvLvGtoRrCPHRHk7JwYChT3al1yb
>   57MFK8chLAgPx2PdHeb6KUB4s7x6E1IJos7DIR2YljEvcCCt75tYufCiOpA1MNN5
>   b718bOTrmlz4Sh7DCxE4HKSyZdJdpMvEcubHVY9to1HIRUmMBpYV+Yc1q+UZMPJ5
>   2evRcoW9fVT2eZ33dlg5Cepo80dEbvvBuraAuAU/3AP6GLolh5C5H7VStm7YDPRZ
>   bUAGDTfAfdDPz03xPJt7stv82YG/xFmCTn9cDX2BSUWFCvAaRMp3CIPH/FZXnWO6
>   uLrdJYjqRmQWTc05sBQ0OtO02I7u/N08qJVT3Qd1a/Cq1NvtnuBnCyL02xlvFpe9
>   HXf6twDOckCOfGGukVuTaVqAMqiuu2ueypnqX2n/oTI0YCXT+TkuGcSOgRyWt9/k
>   IXio1pIBLw9vIixXd9R3GiMhG//krqROgO92gtW4biePzdaJhGQvQKtaNkaKQw+G
>   x4skI4jsXK5FIllwHQ20D37XUbDcnclI/ukQ1jv9SfMgJ2sYsgvVKVoYJj9Og/cP
>   yv80vAri1/8dIv8usMqWPS1H+V1CPzfI78HmmsHH8JgjZkUjkSrkVYtuW4Sr/ukt
>   hemp0STKPcbdwaseszECw8J3np54fDBRnzCyeMUcHwCUYjhmg2CJcgTjyEEB14QO
>   Egz6uE2d1+eegRf50y7W5upr9mdXxeTrkxk+migYYznN0IWaNZvJhB6qbEulBaBw
>   vlE8/+gBI0CP1YRooUA0tFuOBfT5M3/2PGCOaaXWF+YdU7zAMnf+KRiU+jSUz1zl
>   w3fnWKFTesEF2Sq3llCiY8PerFaR799PqBCUvTgiEZPXQiBBaUs44bkdqRK8U31y
>   s/xFnb9kJs25tBPFU/IK28HuX4xCDK5HLPgBJCjeMsSNSqqxFE1OHC4rQnxjrbjB
>   0iSxGFbhLVPNTtHUDehNb7iR3NcT+t0DgDKSFuI7kv1uQaHFX6kQmA0s/AdYl2C/
>   L1low41t4vdXVSgCmJnKFO4Ng1L0M4ACTtnbhgvFWPUhJNR4ZtidqqwK32LDBND2
>   GPD3zDEGfHe9VNazDoV/htJVaCPfGXgTHzA1PjEgsLSrsR5fm54frHMv2CHdSQzn
>   akOT8TOT5lg/IHSUH/+r2HLRL78TGzhtiWaxdyOuVdnBAPCkiMvCcrKgWg/b2r1i
>   +q4HTUu30fw/PmeeN/+SRmkvYShaWOwH94WEfT2q1sIpWL5JZtkRm/pSqqPOY9+o
>   -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

`cat aes128encprivkey.pem`

> !-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
>   Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
>   DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,6263DD33306AA1F9CFD84FB304FACED9
>   N6LFCTguNSfeISBSvciYRuMIg/OER9hy8bjwPkoUaLTBoRbvFtku9KaXwje3Mgw0
>   e+JFtYfjF27ZtHYbk8HFG9z0C20NiwBiFH63U3+YZBJTSKZOHmA2H+d7pT1UV9w5
>   xXXuf7mPEUDLwKVINF8BIez63kay+fAu6Qu2Q9V8KcjITWf/Q+bTmy+LDzOPnnyG
>   z99GE5Ue89z5UtzlMAvASmq403FzAk9xUfj2jc6hASULGrAwKr0qYcsRx5p0Xwcm
>   wzGLYBq3hkZ5BDhdM8wCW0pyazex7M8gX8/CJHuNcUlFt4VzjKfouIw/hPCcvWfy
>   PJ4NrZMNDrlYuVvL4IzP8EDjvqqPqMRXmWmOzmRf3I74E+UKT9ryxiC2qgxyPThR
>   r0Mr0ORv+vUDA4iYN12ERo7hHmCajmgLPI0Muj8HveH7mgYWO8BeM+Z/PGOaKmEE
>   DhGFPg8YLU+74guiuCy4q4Vu8vdFCGnS9mUk+jARnIqGfv6wAoTyWHBGa0oLKz1/
>   xSJhgP5PkppSiekeFBHa496RG7os+usV4xWhOxP/6mupU2WW04hxUgxk/IBqzHB5
>   ZHm+loBbDWuY9H1ZTlUsT3xkriedYBm1nzK3VHLSuPjkcj6sMzCGlZmXKWPfBPw7
>   Q+zkkbapzl6RVdas35C/f1ojsrGuziOZWKimlvL2+Tde9dhjYHu3sKOIrTKLaCWe
>   DkyX7D/zVpCCg3gur+GgG/d8Y/KiwWYV6XjIt1Y1vym/67ZItjrSdgdAadQXUpOG
>   0y70sHxmtaY9lxTZasQnmv9MnZX/33im3gAI2PO4SYmQv2y3ZoQAl5soE7qFWYVO
>   wz4tJgtDW0sQDpGMnzQ7ncnuzCJzx0VbJRDUAAeTUby/m3NtArJ2XR9P21iZ929g
>   T7uxAzO9HBfK2lmtRZQ6+Ab+sDvIJgW6to4VL3TjqfjDe1rffOQrPPGJck13P9/9
>   mhWmZ4pLed0+HcYtfnJ+7ofMUITKdy/e08FgYY76+eoWwkIeAM/O+1ZesDMY4VI5
>   DGbhs+WUwmLVwepjSu61yNgjanL8CPZIJeAiY2vx/LalzmZogoJzrDhUqp/UbYi9
>   wHZsP+0dQgXPkVzNNGuEeJ6a/cTAtbHCjdTL1V3OSRuD19tshoBjxezIgfjF6h7m
>   MivovQe9SLjAvmskoo8lznr7SgQrQgZxtSL/n+90akGdYs529yRgKtmCiR4YrFNd
>   L9dAPQyyT5R0Dky9lkGmbregRxRUFmU/nDlf30cOxs7PJ7BZyqAwYSjRzavLGE+V
>   stzOVgI9dKplQGMev0f/vXTvFLOrmZnK0+6iUoHb9EL2PwOBiD0dD0V2MxQv7Bjj
>   scAis5aopQgpe93E5go0/vPnfVanHgyfnI6FZSKI3A+Ty8s560cDrPNSJBZ4VxHY
>   DQ3/XQu9N38J/JUv14KoGi1ti+Pa4Xan+iq6YW92pP3GGAJnVdVFuYdwZGLP1oPk
>   fH1V5DxvYHn2FH9Ey4fIv7ibbNp3e4eJyT13LLsWWhNkyX1wYmZdgctuGZmlsbBB
>   HjfXgW7Id/TFK6YsVkv2x2veVGd/xU0XtRkOsq/eS1skqLVuxxuUKpG9n1P2X1w3
>   -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

`cat unencryptedprivkey.pem`

> !-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
>   MIIEogIBAAKCAQEAxF0WL8w0fk1dlxibAZKNplzIzHx/cM+VO3D4gRahPBPB1nNW
>   YJ+WGuVDI+U6KN10MLePMsWqDtIDsS4YxWPqqNtYd2OfT6kUBkJE9FcWwMqHkRB2
>   upEPhbi6RGTkKpGxn+tDLMIqizXJkTvDBWrEMsuI882EQgiWVylZ5ElbjnlfU2fs
>   ZRVpr3FsbwI81W4lv9hm+kKe/zsdHK8zUcyaN11aZXiZDHARpzENGlSRg/19J6MD
>   TuJR/om4IPITpvByOSG9LIUwXr8ixbo4AQ5+ejFd1ARYMD0/4HCWA2gwcz8gClJA
>   pS7O4OG0wcQ3LCtFNDAH5oPgIqYutAcG2bny8wIDAQABAoIBAGztgnhDXD9QJYHC
>   6YHGzYMi51TgH0XyMUOHGKNrbUfJYfbXhmwVOwxyb3tDFq9CocjAmtQ8aGjOQbQQ
>   8TbWhX7kJsAb6G0lSvFp45xzjzClaOyk6Gf4PlccsV9tZFDk/1bKCDqU/0q4LLe/
>   IiEoJ+xRkghE0oBbCSMS0kXcF8kBOm9ZqsVE2AnI0MZvHwMn8IFPuIV8NLrLVSZO
>   NvtT20aSf6vAqnUgaEIJD3I1WduI/QwU1GQLE0lXM8++9Q9K07TkV1xqQfuySZp1
>   qBiHCgNBzMxbK9nZIxh6szZNz/xPsLV8WXSSXaqVP3Dnerjpi6YDn1+aqBtcLE8M
>   LxnUQuECgYEA/1saPId7iF4aKU+/jJgw9MzPEUgD1T7tV7EAEsIu73MPyCd8/Y3t
>   Wx4CHAZr5ySL+yS4FgxAE1NRAdGawTelFckuBTjZ8tW2V0KzWvOjSOe0EYIzG36i
>   KTjL7LlwxkZVW1kFo/B5vRtYDqde23I5B3vSq9sDgS/T/PTKyZJp7YMCgYEAxNvj
>   vLP7APczkjD4lfUukzie5N2489p0xLKpXXXqOEmN3fdsRAC7stX8Ebwy/zf/PRDe
>   PABMRUyVxhkEJ3jEJ2iQoicMMcFAzzJHMweqL6mEXEvKNUH0AQvyPAmQKu7tdw6Q
>   2KqRjK8zvYIw1H7NJg5kEUn3yR2eTnuGsmx52dECgYAUs40H9S/VmVNjn/x2aGwn
>   nGb5Dq6I3iYdotLPsoBdlyVjY5glchkY9vDS1s5uma7jeFGYL/wN1QZPMG/sVBeF
>   EZ8yey5oGl1C67xgljnZkjct6DE+fGCnGNynX00+Nbt7wVbMuJUV+J6F6ZmuDq+C
>   5M3qcsHw+jCkZDAAcWc3AwKBgGXfkTQnQ77VLof59brMvgSL6ZZws3TmWUUtW/40
>   tjfYwKTclNeANaIvoJmg9hcjaF+2qfsNAGtgXaW9bmvq0D/AmhB/+oyJALv4veXH
>   kqfFpuyIgCUdc2NTRlERddzx9kuFaynk4xuV00W/6Psef5WxHtHfoG4geLsOq78L
>   6ebxAoGAPPfuY4cHq8PBYcf6++29RUM/n+aCeh+SzO8GpGo+PMaf+6Ax9pCuCZlx
>   DDJ4uGmNcIYOr4fih4+33b2+bfmP95HP77WCYht+5Z6anzyMaliFFoyuE6Z3+FQF
>   ubnsimYRxjDkJyYgyOebDDwwswEg2YQNVDMjTjn6F688ayv18VA=
>   -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Passphrase: pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't.

Generally, speaking, you can only compare two cyphertext together if they share the same IV and key (at least with any modern encryption algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

If you *could* compare the two encrypted keys together, then this would be suggestive of a deep and large weakness of the encryption algorithm. This would be bad news; pray that it does not happen.

Note that even if both files use the same passphrase, they would still differ in IV (or salt for passphrase derivation), and they again should evade attempts at comparisons. If you have two files which use distinct IV, then you should not be able to detect whether they use the same key, or same contents, or both.

Only if you *know* the passphrase(s) can you compare the files, by decrypting both and comparing the clear contents (here, RSA private keys, but what I say applies to any kind of contents).

---

All of the above is about noticing that the two RSA private keys are identical in general. There are particular cases which allow you to conclude:

- If your two files are byte-to-byte identical, then, of course, they are identical, and thus contain the same RSA private key encrypted with the same passphrase and IV.
- If the two files differ in length (length of the Base64-encoded element) then the RSA keys are distinct. You *may* observe a slight difference in size if both files work over the same key but with distinct encryption algorithms (e.g. one uses AES-CBC while the other uses 3DES-CBC). If the same encryption algorithm is used (including mode of operation and padding), then a difference in size implies a difference in size of the *contents*. Since RSA private keys are ASN.1 objets with DER encoding, the cleartext encoded size of a RSA private key is fixed for a given key; therefore, distinct content sizes (even by a single byte) imply distinct keys.

Comment: Or one used excessive padding just to be a pain.  Don't know if anything allows padding an entire block or not, but there isn't any reason it couldn't theoretically be done if someone was trying to avoid same length.

Comment: Since the encryption format used by OpenSSL is not specified anywhere, except as "what OpenSSL does", it is a bit difficult to declare that something is "allowed" or "not allowed". In SSL/TLS (where padding also occurs for CBC encryption), minimal length padding is enforced for SSL 3.0, but TLS 1.0 allows extra blocks.